# Same form , Same barcode(128), Zxing reads only one Barcode( from 2 documents)

Tags: java, pdf, barcode, zxing

I am writing a simple program that extracts barcode from images.

I tried zxing. It worked well. Until I found a something strange.

The organization that i work at, publish forms . Same form (that I got from 2 places in the

org) with the same barcode,  I scanned them in the same machine (same resulotion also) to

pdf format.

zxing is doing the job realy well with first image, And returning the barcode. No luck with

the second image.. I got com.google.zxing.NotFoundException when trying to extract barcode

from second image. The problem occurred with more forms of the organization).

This is the image that Zxing not recognize.

http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=12080994969485224486

This is the one that he does recognize.

http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=30365671784453283753

This is my code :

```
private String handlePdf(File pdfFile) throws Exception { 


    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();  


    PDDocument pdDoc = PDDocument.load(pdfFile);  


    int size = pdDoc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages().size();  


    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {    


        PDPage page = (PDPage) pdDoc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages().get(i); 


        PDResources resources = page.getResources();  


        Map images = resources.getImages();  


           if (images != null) {  


            Iterator<String> imageIter = images.keySet().iterator();  


                   while (imageIter.hasNext()) {  


                  String key = (String) imageIter.next();  


                  PDXObjectImage image = (PDXObjectImage) images.get(key);  


                  String barcode = null ;  


                  barcode = extraceBarcodeFromImage(image.getRGBImage());  


                if(barcode!= null){  


                   sb.append(barcode);  


                   sb.append(",");  


                }  


               }  


         }  

    }  


     return sb.capacity() > 0 ? sb.toString().substring(0, sb.length()-1) : 
                                  "no barcode was found";


}    



private String extraceBarcodeFromImage(BufferedImage image)  


            throws NotFoundException {  


    String finalResult;  


    if (image == null)  


        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not decode image.");  


    Map<DecodeHintType, Object> HINTS;  


    HINTS = new EnumMap(DecodeHintType.class);  


    HINTS.put(DecodeHintType.TRY_HARDER, Boolean.TRUE);  


    HINTS.put(DecodeHintType.POSSIBLE_FORMATS,  


            EnumSet.allOf(BarcodeFormat.class));  


    Map<DecodeHintType, Object> HINTS_PURE;  


    HINTS_PURE = new EnumMap<DecodeHintType, Object>(HINTS);  


    HINTS_PURE.put(DecodeHintType.PURE_BARCODE, Boolean.TRUE);  


    LuminanceSource source = new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(image);  


    BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new GlobalHistogramBinarizer(  


            source));  


    MultiFormatReader barcodeReader = new MultiFormatReader();   


    Result result;  


    result = barcodeReader.decode(bitmap, HINTS_PURE);   


    finalResult = String.valueOf(result.getText());  


    return finalResult;  


}
```

Thank you for any help you can provide in this situation.

Comment: Can you provide the actual PDFs for analysis?

Comment: I provided 2 links to the PDFs. Are they broken?

Comment: Ok. When I tried downloading from my mobile phone, some html was stored, no PDFs. On my desktop now actual PDFs are downloaded.

Comment: Thank you, I will be grateful to get your opinion .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue simply is the fairly low image quality.

Look at the working bar code at some magnification:

[image: magnified working bar code]

The quality is not good but it is good enough.

Now compare it to the not working bar code:

[image: magnified not working bar code]

It is somewhat rotated and (maybe due to the rotation) the bars are very fringed. Too fringed for zxing to recognize the bar code.

I went through that with a debugger, and even making it look at every single row of the image (without manipulation it looks only at 256 evenly spaced rows), it didn't find any row it could read successfully as a bar code.

Thus, you either have to improve the quality of the scans (higher resolution, making sure the document is not rotated, ...) or have to look for a bar code reader library which does not merely look at image columns or rows individually but instead tries to recognize larger structures. I'm not deep enough into these things to be able to recommend any.